# Adding Dynamic capabilities to wordpress RSS feed through elementor

Tags: dynamic, rss, elementor

Hi Hoping someone can shed some light on how this can be done.

So here's the scenario I'm in.

1. I have a frontend submission from that collects people's submitted blog url.
2. I then created a page based on those submissions and want to display their blog url with Wordpress RSS feed.

The current problem:
If you try to add the Wordpress RSS Feed widget into your Elementor page, you'll see that it's requires a defined link (static). So there's no option point to dynamic data in this case. Which ideally would point to the form submission's meta data or custom field data that's entered.

I've tried multiple RSS feeds plugins and addons and none provide this kind of option. Is there a code snippet to make this possible? Or a plugin that would make this likely to happen.

**Few things to note.**

- I don't want to import the actual post to my site.
- I'm using Elementor/pro, crocoblock (jet engine) to build my frontend submission form.
- I've created Single page template to render all the submitted data.

Let me know if there's any clarification needed above. Hope I explained enough of it that it makes sense.

I’m trying to figure out a way to do this either with their default rss feed via another shortcode plugin that can pull that information? or some other plugin entirely that supports dynamically linking to a data field from the front end submission form.

To Recap:
You fill out your website blog url
then some how the submitted information gets parsed into a page that shows your latest 5 blog posts as links or whatever parameters I define in the widget/plugin that the RSS feed would be.

Answer (score 0):

Two years too late, but maybe someone is still interested. Write the code in the functions-php of the child-theme, replace "replace_name_of_acf_field" and then use the shortcode [rss_acf].
I had the code created by ChatGPT and it works like a charm! ^^

```
function rss_acf_shortcode($atts) {
  $url = get_field('replace_name_of_acf_field');
  
  // Check if the URL is valid
  if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    // Generate the RSS feed with the URL
    $rss = fetch_feed($url);
    
    // Check if the RSS feed was generated correctly
    if(!is_wp_error($rss)) {
      // Get the number of entries contained in the RSS feed
      $max_items = $rss->get_item_quantity(5);
      
      // Get the RSS feed entries
      $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $max_items);
      
      // Create a variable to return the RSS feed
      $output = '<div class="custom-rss">';
      
      // Go through each entry of the RSS feed and add it to the output
      foreach($rss_items as $item) {
        $output .= '<div class="custom-rss-item">';
        $output .= '<h3 class="custom-rss-title"><a href="'.$item->get_permalink().'">'.$item->get_title().'</a></h3>';
        $output .= '<div class="custom-rss-content1">'.substr($item->get_content(), 0, 200).'...</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
      }
      
      // Close the RSS output
      $output .= '</div>';
      
      // Return the generated RSS output
      return $output;
    }
  }
}
add_shortcode('rss_acf', 'rss_acf_shortcode');
```